# jQuery selector returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a div class called `question_image1` with about four labels inside. My input is wrapped inside of my label `<label><input/></label>`, so I didn't use the `for` attribute of a label.

I'm trying to select all labels that weren't the ones that were clicked inside of the class.

```
$(".question_image1").click(function(event) {
    $('.question_image1 label').not(event.target).style.opacity = "30%";
});
```

Is there an obvious problem here? One possibility is that there's a level of div between the question_image1 class and the label. Would that be an issue?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use a DOM `style` property on a jQuery object. Use the jQuery `.css()` method.

```
$('.question_image1 label').not(event.target).css("opacity", "30%");
```

But `event.target` is will be multiple elements because of event bubbling. So I think you should use

```
$('.question_image1').not(this).find("label").css("opacity", "30%");
```

`this` will be the element that the event was bound to.

Comment: The code is changing all of the labels, including the one that was the target (confirmed by console.log). Any ideas?

Comment: `event.target` is a DIV, not a label.

Comment: console.log prints an img and input element. Either event.target is the label that contains those two, or the propogation makes it so that both elements are clicked, right? How to make it so that only images not clicked will change?

Comment: That's event bubbling.

Comment: Use `$(this)` instead of `$(event.target)`. Or maybe `$(event.currentTarget)`.

Comment: I have already tried $(this), $(event.currentTarget) also did not work. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Try using `event.stopPropagation()`